# Windows 10 won't hibernate - searching for command

Tags: windows-10, command-line, hibernate

my win 10 laptop can't hibernate, I came across this problem once before, all I had to do was execute command in CMD to find which programs are preventing me from hibernating, but I can't find that any more.
When i press hibernate button, my screen goes black for a second but turns back to login screen seconds after.
Do you guys have some help for me ?

Comment: In an admin command prompt make sure that you have done `powercfg -h on` and then if that isnt working have a look at `powercfg -requests`

Comment: Thank you but it didn't help
(executed with admin priv.)
C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg -h on      
C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg -requests
DISPLAY:
None.

SYSTEM:
None.

AWAYMODE:
None.

EXECUTION:
None.

PERFBOOST:
None.

ACTIVELOCKSCREEN:
None.